# How to add sizes of all files with the same name in UNIX Shell scripts

Tags: unix, shell

I'm new here and I want to ask how to add sizes of files with the same name? My file names are actually different from each other but I cut them so I could get files that are grouped together.

here are my original files with sizes (sample)

sample.txt has this data inside:

1. 12345   a_1.txt
2. 12234   b_1.txt
3. 32123   c_1.txt
4. 11122   a_2.txt

Now I cut the filenames inside sample.txt to remove those characters starting from '_' (underscore). They become like this:

1. 12345   a
2. 12234   b
3. 32123   c
4. 11122   a

Now I want to add sizes of all files with same filename as seen above. Output should be like this:

1. 23467   a
2. 12234   b
3. 32123   c

Please help. Thanks a lot guys. I'm stuck here for hours now

Comment: I'm not sure if line numbers exist in `sample.txt` and you want them in the output. It looks like numbered list so maybe not. Please paste your file and desired output as `code sample` to avoid confusion.

Comment: Wow Kamil, it worked! Can you please explain the code to me? Especially the awk command. I'm not familiar with it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there are no line numbers in `sample.txt`:

```
cut -f 1 -d _ sample.txt | awk '{a[$2] += $1} END{for (i in a) print a[i], i}'
```

You may want to add `| sort -k 2` at the end.

---

EDIT1 - explanation as requested:

The `cut` command cuts every line with `_` delimiter and saves the first part only. You have already done it with your original file.

Then the `awk` command finds two fields in every line. We call them *size* and *name*, but `awk` refers to them as `$1` and `$2` internally. For every line it increments one element of an array `a` (the name `a` is arbitrarily chosen and has nothing to do with filename in the sample). The *name* `$2` tells which element to increment -- it is an index; the *size* `$1` is the incrementation value. `awk` is smart enough to initialize `a` element with `0` as it is mentioned for the first time. The particular element is incremented every time its index (*name*) appears as a second field of the input line. At the end (after the last line of the input) `awk` goes through every known index of `a` and prints the value (which is now *cumulative size*) and an index (*name*).

Comment: Wow Kamil, it worked! Can you please explain the code to me? Especially the awk command. I'm not familiar with it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

To get the total of every file starting with `a_`  you could do this:

```
du -c a_*  | grep total
```

`du` works out the size of all the files then `-c` totals the sizes.  The grep just extracts the total rather than all the individual files.

Comment: Thank you Paul but it's not working.

I just want to clear that those 2 set of files are in .txt. I'll edit my question again. Sorry